# Limiting distribution of $nF[X_{(2)}]$?

Tags: limits, order-statistics

[image]
Hello.

I am trying to work on a problem above.

What I know so far is that

$$\begin{align}
nF_{Y_2}(y)&=n\left([1-F(x)]^n+nF(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-1}\right)\\
&=  n[1-F(x)]^{n-1}[1+(n-1)F(x)] \\
\end{align}$$

but I am stuck here.

Can someone help me out?

What also confuses me is that the input of $F$ should be a number, but for some reason a random variable $Y_2$ is plugged in and I am not sure if what I am doing is right...

Comment: You want to consider $nF(Y_2)$ (with $Y_2$ (random variable) plugged into the CDF of the original random variable), rather than $nF_{Y_2}(y)$ ($n$ times the CDF of $Y_2$).

Comment: Oh, I was right that $Y_2$ was supposed to be plugged in. . . then how do I proceed from there?  I do not understand how $Pr[X \le Y_2]$ would work because now you have a random variable in the input ... :(

Comment: Just in general, if $Y$ is a random variable and $F$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$, $F(Y)$ means "plug in $Y$ to the CDF of $X$ (as a function)". It doesn't mean $\mathbb{P}(X\le Y)$. So $F(Y)$ is just some function of a random variable (and hence is itself a random variable!). For example, imagine if $X$ were a random variable with CDF $F(x) = x^2$ for $x\in [0,1]$. If $Y$ is a random variable that always takes values in $[0,1]$, then $F(Y)$ would refer to the random variable $Y^2$.